# .NET: What is the object header used for?

Tags: .net

In .NET there are 8 bytes of overhead for each object. 4 bytes are a pointer to the object's type. What are the other 4 bytes, known as the object header, used for?

Note: the question was asked in 2010 and is 32 bit specific. The overhead is bitness dependent: 1 pointer-size for the "object's type" (method table) and 1 pointer-size for the object header. So, that's 2*4 bytes for 32 bit and 2*8 bytes for 64 bit applications.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629100/c-objects-allocated-on-heap

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150515023057/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx) discusses a lot of internals, including what goes into each object instance. Basically, it's the type information and a syncblock pointer (because ever object can potentially be locked upon)

Comment: Syncblock index, not pointer.  It can also store the hash code, depending on usage.  Plus several GC related bits.