# Reflection, compile-time type, runtime type, assemblies, and how they fit together

Tags: c#, reflection

I've been trying to piece together how reflection, compile-time type, runtime type, assemblies, and metadata fit together in C#. My understanding so far is that reflection allows the runtime to introspect upon the compiled code's assembly metadata. This metadata contains information about the methods and types in our program. For example, we get an object's type.

My questions are:

1. When we're getting an object's type via reflection, are we getting the runtime type or static type?
2. If we're able to get the runtime type from metadata, how is this happening?
3. Couldn't I just use "GetType()"?
4. And an assembly is compiled code, runtime types aren't known yet, so how can the runtime type be extracted from an assembly's metadata?

As an example:

```
Base b = new Derived();
Console.WriteLine(b.GetType());
```

I understand that Derived is logged. But how? If GetType retrieves the type via reflection, which consults the assembly's metadata, how is the runtime type being logged? Doesn't the metadata only contain type information based on compile time?

Just after some clarification, big or small, whatever is necessary. And please correct anything I've said that's incorrect.

Comment: "*When we're getting an object's type via reflection*" -- what exactly do you mean by this? It sounds initially like you're doing `someObject.GetType()`, but point 3 suggests this is wrong. So it's not clear what you're referring to.

Comment: You call GetType on an instance of a class. If you already have a type calling GetType on that won't help. And metadata can't be more then the type information. Maybe the question gets more clear when you add an example of what you are doing or what you want to do.

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't aware that "GetType()" was itself an example of reflection.

Comment: For how `GetType` works, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506117/net-what-is-the-object-header-used-for). Each object instance contains enough data to get the corresponding `Type` object -- every single object had a header which you can query, and which tells you the type of that object. In practice, the object header contains a pointer to an area in the assembly metadata which contains the type information, so a `Derived` object has a pointer to the area of metadata describing containing the type info for `Derived`, `Base` has a pointer to the area for `Base`, etc

Comment: The "Derived" Type is known at compile time and is part of the assemblies type metadata and is known by the instance of that type you create at runtime even if the variable pointing to that instance is only of the base type. The type of the reference to that type is irrelevant the instance of the type knows its "real" type.

Comment: I understand that the Derived Type is known at compile time and that it therefore will be in the assembly's metadata, but how then does GetType (through reflection) know that at runtime "b" is pointing to a Derived Type? Is this explained by what the object's header points to?

Comment: @Calculon Yes, as my comment and linked article explain. The object header of `Derived` contains a pointer to an area of the assembly metadata which holds the `Type` definition for the `Derived` type