# How does C# create an instance of a class?

Tags: c#, .net

```
public class MyClass
{
    int i = 0;
    string str = "here";
    MyStruct mystruct;
    B b;
    ArrayList myList = new ArrayList(10);

    public MyClass()
    {
    }
    ....
}

public struct MyStruct
{
    public int i;
    public float f;
}

public class B
{
    ...
}
```

Want to learn how an instance of a class is created in the background. When this statement

```
 MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
```

is evaluated. What will happen in the backgroud? My following statements are correct or not (for 32-bit OS machine)?

1. A memory space will be created and referenced as `myClass`;
2. within above memory space, 4 bytes is used for the value of `int i`;
3. within above memory space, 4 bytes is used for the reference of `string str`; the actual value of the `str` is stored in other location (where?)
4. within above memory space, 8 bytes is used for the value of `MyStruct mystruct` (because MyStruct is 8 bytes);
5. within above memory space, 4 bytes is used for the reference of the `B b` object; memory for b object will be allocated in somewhere else when it is instantiated;
6. within above memory space, 4 bytes is used for the reference of the `ArrayList myList`; actual memory space for `ArrayList myList` is allocated in other place and referenced in here as `myList`;
7. another 4 or 8 bytes from above memory space is used for object metadata;
8. ...;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the basic idea in place.  The actual specifics of this, aside from what you include, is implementation specific.  However, for a couple of your points:

3) The actual string is typically stored in its own memory space, just like any other class.  However, since you're using a string literal in this case, it'll most likely be in the string intern pool, which is (I believe) stored in the large object heap.  For details on string interning, see [String.Intern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern.aspx).  (If you allocated the string on the fly, instead of using a literal, the string would be stored in the normal managed heap of your application.)

Answer (score 1):

That's about it.

The string is stored in the string table rather than as a free floating object in the heap. It's important to note that only one instance of that string is instantiated, regardless of the number of instances of `MyClass` that are instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

> 7.another 4 or 8 bytes from above memory space is used for object
>   metadata

It would be 8 bytes. 4 for the syncblock and 4 for type information.

You can find more information regarding the subject in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629100/c-objects-allocated-on-heap).